# Running applet in browser

Tags: java, browser, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I know that the question has been asked many times, but I have problem that I could not solve normaly. I am codeing a RPG game and I would to run in self-standing in browser.
 the DIR looks like:

```
C:\Users\Tomasz\SimpleRPG
```

that is main folder of project, but I have here `.settings` `bin` and `src` folders, and in each i have package foldes `rpg`.
I have found code to run it from HTML:

```html
<applet code=main.class name=main archive=main.jar
    width=640 height=640>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="ffffff">
    <param name="fontcolor" value="000000">
    Your browser is not Java enabled.
</applet>
```

I am wondering where to put that file to run it. When I drop it to `bin/rpg`, it brings me error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: main (wrong name: rpg/main)
```

If I drop it to `src/rpg` I have another error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: main.class
```

And if I copy all `.class` and all `.java` to one folder `SimpleRPG/all` and drop script there:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: main (wrong name: rpg/main)
```

I have to say that I have also graphics in that project in `bin/img`.

Can some one advise me what to do?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the class file is located in the `rpg` package.  So the applet element should be more along the lines of:

```html
<applet code='rpg.main' 
    name='main' 
    archive='main.jar'
    width='640' height='640'>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="ffffff">
    <param name="fontcolor" value="000000">
    Your browser is not Java enabled.
</applet>
```

This should work if `main.jar` is in the same directory as the HTML that loads it.

Comment: Still ClassNotFoundExcepion

Comment: Show the edited HTML and **copy/pasted** error message as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18172043/edit).  Also answer my question in point 1) of my comment.  I do not ask these questions to see my own words in writing, but expect an *answer*.

Comment: It starts applet but it seems to be white and nothig appears now i dont have errors. Sorry for beeing late in reply. And i have made a simple hello applet, and that worked.